# Why would my roommate's pc show up on netstat?

Tags: wireless-networking

My connection was really slow today so I ran netstat to see if there was something weird going on. The first five entries surprised me:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State 

 TCP    10.100.2.3:2869        DJ-Blade:62606         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    10.100.2.3:2869        DJ-Blade:62607         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    10.100.2.3:2869        DJ-Blade:62609         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    10.100.2.3:2869        DJ-Blade:62611         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    10.100.2.3:2869        DJ-Blade:62618         TIME_WAIT
```

I looked in Explorer, and under network was a machine labelled DJ-Blade, which I'm assuming is my roommate's. From what I can find it seems port 2869 is used in UPnP and SSDP discovery, from http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;832017. I checked my sharing settings, and for some reason I was in a homegroup I hadn't joined before. Once I left that, there were two final entries from DJ:

```
 TCP    10.100.2.3:5357        DJ-Blade:62757         TIME_WAIT
 TCP    10.100.2.3:52864       DJ-Blade:wsd           TIME_WAIT
```

The first entry on port 5357 is for network discovery, which I just disabled. I'm just concerned about the mysterious homegroup and the fact that I've never seen any of my roommates show up here. Is this normal?

Comment: Do netstat -aon (that -o is important), -o shows PID. Then check task manager view..select columns..pid. you can use tasklist command too. find out what process it is

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your roommate didn't join your computer to the homegroup?

There isn't a way to remotely join computers without remote execution.

Comment: If it requires physical access then I'm sure